# How to Mutate an Array in a Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, immutability

I've tried the following in a Playground:

```
var d1 = [String: [String]]()
d1["a"] = [String]()

var a1 = d1["a"]!
a1.append("s1")

println(d1)
```

The output is: `[a: []]`
I was hoping for: `[a: ["s1"]]`

What would be the right way to mutate an array in a dictionary?

Comment: All the answers helped me understand this better. Unfortunately, it seems I can accept only one. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In swift, structures are copied by value when they get assigned to a new variable. So, when you assign `a1` to the value in the dictionary it actually creates a copy. Here's the line I'm talking about:

```
var a1 = d1["a"]!
```

Once that line gets called, there are actually two lists: the list referred to by `d1["a"]` and the list referred to by `a1`. So, only the second list gets modified when you call the following line:

```
a1.append("s1")
```

When you do a print, you're printing the first list (stored as the key `"a"` in dictionary `d1`). Here are two solutions that you could use to get the expected result.

**Option1: Append directly to the array inside `d1`.**

```
var d1 = [String : [String]]()
d1["a"] = [String]()
d1["a"]?.append("s1")
println(d1)
```

**Option 2: Append to a copied array and assign that value to `"a"` in `d1`.**

```
var d1 = [String : [String]]()
d1["a"] = [String]()
var a1 = d1["a"]!
a1.append("s1")
d1["a"] = a1
println(d1)
```

The first solution is more performant, since it doesn't create a temporary copy of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29190251/1548472) of [@jfocht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783978/jfocht) here is

**Option 3: Append within function where array is passed by reference**

```
func myAdd(s : String, inout arr : [String]?) {
    if arr == nil
    {
        arr = [String]()
    }
    arr?.append(s)
}

var d1 = [String : [String]]()

myAdd("s1", &d1["a"])
myAdd("s2", &d1["b"])

println(d1) // [ b: [s2], a: [s1]]
```

Added some sugar in the sense that it actually creates a new array if given a dictionary key with no arrays attached currently.

Answer (score 1):

Swift `Array` and `Dictionary` are not an objects like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. They are `struct`. So by doing `var a1 = d1["a"]` would be like doing `var a = point.x` and then change `a` but of course the `point.x` will not change.

So by doing this instead:

```
d1["a"] = []
d1["a"]!.append("")
```

Would be like doing `point.x = 10`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a new value for key `"a"` inside your dictionary.
Which means:

`d1["a"] = a1`