# Swift 3: Change item in dictionary

Tags: swift, list, dictionary, mutable

I'm saving lists in a dictionary. These lists need to be updated. But when searching for an item, I need [] operator. When I save the result to a variable, a copy is used. This can not be used, to change the list itself:

```
        item = dicMyList[key]
        if item != nil {
            // add it to existing list
            dicMyList[key]!.list.append(filename)
//            item?.list.append(filename)
        }
```

I know, that I need the uncommented code above, but this accesses and searches again in dictionary. How can I save the result, without searching again? (like the commented line)
I want to speed up the code.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189955/how-to-mutate-an-array-in-a-dictionary-swift-objects) your case?

Comment: What do you mean by "*this accesses and searches again in dictionary*"? The very nature of a dictionary means that it shouldn't require searching through in order to find the value for a key – the lookup is done in O(1) time.

Comment: yes, that is the case. :-)
"this accesses and searches again in dictionary" means, that the object dicMyList[key] is already available. And even if it is O(1) it needs additional computation which is not neccessary. Like in the old days, when in C I got the pointer to the struct, I can directly use it. *p = newValue

Comment: @Peter71 Unless you've profiled it, and identified it as a bottleneck, you shouldn't be attempting to perform such small optimisations. In any case, given that value types in Swift have copy-on-write behaviour, there's no guarantee that when you mutate `dicMyList` that the memory location of your array value will be the same before and after the mutation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't think that this is a bottleneck, but I always try to write optimal code at the first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

In case you needn't verify whether the inner `list` was actually existing or not prior to adding element `fileName`, you could use a more compact solution making use of the `nil` coalescing operator.

```
// example setup
var dicMyList = [1: ["foo.sig", "bar.cc"]] // [Int: [String]] dict
var key = 1
var fileName = "baz.h"

// "append" (copy-in/copy-out) 'fileName' to inner array associated 
// with 'key'; constructing a new key-value pair in case none exist
dicMyList[key] = (dicMyList[key] ?? []) + [fileName]
print(dicMyList) // [1: ["foo.sig", "bar.cc", "baz.h"]]

// same method used for non-existant key
key = 2
fileName = "bax.swift"
dicMyList[key] = (dicMyList[key] ?? []) + [fileName]
print(dicMyList) // [2: ["bax.swift"], 1: ["foo.sig", "bar.cc", "baz.h"]]
```

Comment: That looks nice, but "dicMyList[key] = (dicMyList[key] ?? []) + [fileName]" also needs two times computing dicMyList[key]. That's I like to avoid. I like to save the result and use it again. But it seems to be impossible right now in Swift 3.0, if I read all the answers to the other posts correctly.

Comment: @Peter71 do you know that this will be an issue performance-wise? _Generally_, much work can be put into performance optimizations that would never, in the end, show up as issues in a profiler if left "nonoptimized".

Comment: Thanks. No I don't think that it's a bottleneck. It's just to write good code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries and arrays are value types. So if you change an entry you'll need to save it back into the dictionary.

```
if var list = dicMyList[key] {
    list.append(filename)
    dicMyList[key] = list
} else {
    dicMyList[key] = [filename]
}
```

Comment: Or instead of `dicMyList[key] = list` you could use `dicMyList.updateValue(list, forKey: key)`, but either is fine :) I prefer @appzYourLife's for clarity though

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late, but you can do something like this:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Array<String> {

    mutating func append(_ element: String) {
        if self == nil {
            self = [element]
        }
        else {
            self!.append(element)
        }
    }
}

var dictionary = [String: [String]]()

dictionary["Hola"].append("Chau")
```

You can try this in the Playground and then adapt to your needs.